# multiplying two arrays of different dimensions in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

for my assignment I have to multiply two matrices together to create a new one. I will then sort the new one from an inherited class. My question is what is the format to multiply two arrays of different dimensions my first one `a1d` is 5 integers. My other one `a2d` is a 5x10 array. What is the correct way to multiply these together being that they are different sizes and dimensions. Do I multiply a1d by every row of a2d? I am going to output the products to a 1 dimensional array so that sorting is easier. I have drawn out the two arrays as tables to help me visualize it. I will attach the short code I have and my illustration. This is in C++.

```
#pragma once
#include<ctime>
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
class matrices
{
private:
    int* a1d[5]; // Old Code:int* a1d = new int[5];
    int** a2d = new int* [5];
public:
    int* matrix;
    matrices();
    ~matrices();
    int* filla1d();
    int* filla2d();
    int* multiply();
};
```

```
int* matrices::filla1d() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        a1d[i] = new int;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        *a1d[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
    }

    return *a1d;
}


int* matrices::filla2d() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        a2d[i] = new int[10];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            a2d[i][j] = rand() % 10 + 1;
            cout << a2d[i][j] << endl;
        }
    }
    return *a2d;
}



int* matrices::multiply() {


}
```

it is required that I only use pointer type variables and pointer returning functions, though that doesn't change too much. I don't know how they should be multiplied, and because of that, I am not sure how many values will be generated from the multiplication for the size of the new array. Thanks in advance!

Here is what I have designed to multiply them together. I have changed how my pointer arrays are allocated. My problem now is that it tells me that "expression must have arithmetic or unscoped enum type". Where I have `matrix[i] =(a1d[index1] * a2d[index1][index2]);` I thought maybe a1d needed to be a pointer type but it gives me the error where it can't convert from int* to int.

Also, when I debug, my `a1d` and `matrix` arrays allocate perfectly and show the correct number of data slots when moused over. However, `a2d` only shows one pointer which points to 5 in this case. I followed the syntax I have seen online for an array of pointers to create a 2d array.

```
int* matrices::filla1d() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        a1d[i] = new int;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        *a1d[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
    }

    return *a1d;
}


int* matrices::filla2d() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        a2d[i] = new int[10];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            a2d[i][j] = rand() % 10 + 1;
        }
    }
    return *a2d;
}



int* matrices::multiply() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        matrix[i] = new int;
    }
    int index1 = 0;
    int index2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        matrix[i] = (a1d[index1] * a2d[index1][index2]);
        index1++;
        index2++;
    }

    return *matrix;
}
```

```
class matrices
{
private:
    int* a1d[5];
    int** a2d = new int*[5];
public:
    int* matrix[50];
    matrices();
    ~matrices();
    int* filla1d();
    int* filla2d();
    int* multiply();
};
```

Edit 2:

I changed the line to fill up the new `matrix` to say 
`*matrix[i] = a2d[index1][index2] * *a1d[index1];`
Now I get an access violation error on this line. I have `matrix` allocated the same way I have `a1d` allocated, what can cause my access violation?

Comment: I strongly recommend making an attempt at solving the problem yourself and asking questions, if necessary, about the attempt. You might get it right. You might only require a bit of correction. You might need a lot of correction, but at least we have something we can use to determine what kind of help you need. Furthermore, do not underestimate the social benefits of showing your work. People around here aren't keen on doing work for people who haven't tried to do it themselves.

Comment: Multiplying matrixes of different sizes requires that the first matrix has the same number of columns as the number of rows in the second. Thus you are required to multipliy a 1x5 matrix (which is sometime called a vector) by the 5x10 matrix.This creates a new matrix which is the number of rows in the first one and number of columns in the second one. Check wiki for details then try solving the problem.

Comment: @user4581301 I edited above. I tried to set up a function to multiply them, but I am having a problem with multiplying from my 2d array.